# Must a constant expression be evaluated to an integral type?

Tags: c++, constant-expression

Lets say I have the following:

```
int i = 1;
String str("abc");
```

Would `str` be consider a constant expression?

From lots of C++ books, it seems a constant expression must be evaluated to an integral type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would str be consider a constant expression?

No, it won't. In C++11 there is a new keyword `constexpr` introduced that helps generalize the notion of constant expressions. If `String` constructor from `"abc"` is trivial enough then it could be declared `constexpr`; however such constructor probably has to allocate memory so it wouldn't qualify.

Comment: In the above case, variable i might not be a constant expression too since it could be changed, am i right? A constant expression must be something that is definite and wont change - hence the compiler can determine its value. Only thing i am puzzle is does it needs to be an integral type? How about a constant string like const string("abc");?

Comment: @yapkm01: Yes, in C++03 constant expressions must be of integral type.